# Device sometimes not detected in eclipse when connected with USB cable

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to run my android project on device(Samsung galaxy),But sometime eclipse don't detect my device. I restart eclipse IDE and device then its detects, sometimes not. i also check after kill adb in DDMS but its don't detects.I am using ubuntu 11.10 and eclipse kepler version. I hope there should be a solution. Please anybody help to resolve this problem. Thanks for your valuable time and consideration in advance.

Comment: are you using the original usb cable? Or any issue with the cable? check

Comment: i am using original usb calbe. no issue with the cable i also checked with a brand new original cable but its not work.

Comment: Did you check the `Device` View ?

Comment: yes i checked but there is no Hard Device found.

Comment: I Need to know the paths of adb you are using 1. Hit "which adb" on terminal 2. Eclipse sdk location

Comment: adb path :  /home/tli2/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
eclipse sdk location : /home/tli2/Eclipse/eclipse/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try another cable. I had a similar problem with a Galaxy Nexus and it turned out to be a faulty cable.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, i changed the cable but its not working

Answer (score 0):

once try this in your command prompt with correct path ./adb kill-server && sudo ./adb devices

Answer (score 0):

maybe the API level of your device is not enough for the widgets you are using in your app?
it happend to me while i was trying to launch a GridView on my cell.

Comment: API level is fine, app is working fine in the device but sometime eclipse doesn't detect.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are selecting PTP/MTP manually or is it being set to one of those automatically:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Screenshot_2011-12-11-10-43-59-281x500.png

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to try these:

1. Download and install [Samsung Android usb driver. Click Here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows) to download.
2. Check whether you have enabled developer option in your android device.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. Samsung Android usb driver needs for windows, developer option is enabled.